# After installing Laravel Socialite, Query scope method and relationships not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-socialite

I have a scope method "scopeUserResponse" in user model:

```
public function scopeUserResponse($query,$user_id)
{ 
    return $query->where('users.id' , $user_id)->select(
                'users.id as user_id',
                'users.username as user_name',
                'users.first_name as user_fname',
                'users.last_name as user_lname'
            );
}
```

I am calling it from controller, like:

```
$userdetail = User::userResponse($user->id)->first();
```

it was working fine but now its giving me error

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::userResponse does not exist.
```

Even my relationship methods are not working after installing Socialite.

Comment: User::userResponse ? or scopeUserResponse ?

Comment: its scopeUserResponse